# why does spring boot war does not generate web.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

In my spring boot app I have the following configuration to generate a war.

```
    apply plugin: 'war'

    war {
        baseName = 'sales_service_shared'
        version =  '0.0.1'
    }

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
...
}
```

Everything is working fine and the war is generated.

But the web.xml is missing.
how can a war work without web.xml ?

Comment: place in Apache tomcat server in Root Folder and Rerun the server.

Comment: web.xml is not required in newer Servlet specifications. All that work is now done by annotations provided in I think Servlet 3+ specs. So you can use newer Tomcat versions and deploy w/o web.xml

Comment: BTW, neither Spring nor gradle will generate a web.xml file for you. If you need or want a web.xml file, you must write it by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you are deploying your application in a container supporting the latest *JEE* specs i.e. *Servlet 3.0+ environments*, the *web.xml* (aka deployment descriptor) **is not mandatory**.

Actually all the underlying *servlet* initializing goes programmatically through a `org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer` implementation for a *Spring* applicationand similar mechanism.